# multifile to aws s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Im trying to understand few things. I just want to know whether mfs/multifile(file data is split and kept in different servers) files in abinito can be pushed to aws s3 bucket directly? . As of now we are converting mfs/multifile file to serial and then pushing it to the aws s3 bucket.

I did some research on this and came across an term called multi part upload api in aws. I went through the aws support docs and understood the concept of it. My doubt s whether it can be used to push the multi files to aws s3 bucket?.

Thanks! :-) appreciate your valuable response :-)

Comment: S3 Multipart upload is just a mechanism to upload/download huge file. You need to write tools that to act as middleman , to take files from mfs and upload to S3.

Answer (score 1):

***Disclaimer: I work for [Minio](https://minio.io).***

---

You can alternatively use [Minio client aka mc](https://github.com/minio/mc), its open source and compatible with AWS S3 API. Minio client handles multipart mechanism for you natively. Please check [docs](https://docs.minio.io/docs/minio-client-complete-guide) for deployment and examples.

Hope it helps.